# Can SVG render partially if gzipped and chunk-transferred?

Tags: svg, content-encoding, transfer-encoding, chunked-encoding

I have some large, dynamically generated SVGs that are being served over a relatively slow internet connection.  I'm trying to optimize them to be viewable as fast as possible.  If I set the server to Content-Encoding: gzip and Transfer-Encoding: chunked, will any SVG viewers take advantage of that and render it partially, as it is transferred?  If not, are there other ways to get it to render as-it-streams?  I could break it up into several SVG pieces but that will be a lot of work, I was hoping for server settings...

The most common users use IE7 with the Adobe SVG Viewer plugin.

I doubt it matters but I'm serving with C#/ASP.NET and IIS6.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is streamable (as well as gzipped chunked encoding), so theoretically it is possible to display only partially downloaded file.

I don't know if IE+SVG actually does it. Test it! Do something equivalent of:

```
echo('<rect…>'); 
flush(); 
sleep(10);
echo('<rect…>');
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at least in Chrome and Firefox SVG does render partially while being displayed directly or inside an `<iframe>`, but in an `<img>` it is not rendered until fully loaded.